# A question regarding existence of solutions to polynomial equations in fields.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory

Let $k$ be an odd integer greater than or equal to $3$, and let $F$ be a field. Also, let $m$ be an odd integer such that $k \geq m \geq 3$. If every $k$-th degree polynomial equation in $F$ has a solution in $F$, must every $m$-th degree polynomial equation in $F$ also have a solution in $F$? Or, is there a counterexample, meaning, is there a field $F$ and odd integers $k$ and $m$ with $k \geq m \geq 3$, such that $F$ has solutions for every $k$-th degree polynomials, but there is at least one $m$-th degree equation which has no solutions in $F$?

Comment: I feel like letting $F$ equal "the smallest subfield of $\Bbb C$ that is closed under taking degree-$k$ extensions" will be a counterexample, at least when $\gcd(m,k)=1$.